# Frustum intersection code returns bad value

Tags: c++

I'm implementing some frustum-related code, and the culling test returns nothing even when there are many visible objects. My mathematical support library does not provide plane support or anything like that, so much of this code is written from scratch with little available testing. If you have any suggestions as to the failure point, please advise. Fortunately there is not much of it, so Little'Wall'o'Code follows:

```
    class Plane {
    public:
        Plane() {
            r0 = Math::Vector(0,0,0);
            normal = Math::Vector(0,1,0);
        }
        Plane(Math::Vector p1, Math::Vector p2, Math::Vector p3) {
            r0 = p1;
            normal = Math::Cross(p2 - p1, p3 - p1);
        }
        Math::Vector r0;
        Math::Vector normal;
    };
    class Frustum {
    public:
        Frustum(
            const std::array<Math::Vector, 8>& points
            )
        {
            planes[0] = Plane(points[0], points[1], points[2]);
            planes[1] = Plane(points[4], points[5], points[6]);
            planes[2] = Plane(points[0], points[1], points[4]);
            planes[3] = Plane(points[2], points[3], points[6]);
            planes[4] = Plane(points[0], points[2], points[4]);
            planes[5] = Plane(points[1], points[3], points[5]);
        }
        Plane planes[6];
    };

       // http://www.cescg.org/CESCG-2002/DSykoraJJelinek/index.html
       bool Intersects(Math::AABB lhs, const Frustum& rhs) const {
            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                Math::Vector pvertex = lhs.TopRightFurthest;
                Math::Vector nvertex = lhs.BottomLeftClosest;
                if (rhs.planes[i].normal.x <= -0.0f) {
                    std::swap(pvertex.x, nvertex.x);
                } 
                if (rhs.planes[i].normal.y <= -0.0f) {
                    std::swap(pvertex.y, nvertex.y);
                }
                if (rhs.planes[i].normal.z <= -0.0f) {
                    std::swap(pvertex.z, nvertex.z);
                }
                if (Math::Dot(nvertex - rhs.planes[i].r0, rhs.planes[i].normal) > 0.0f) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Also of note is that I'm using a left-handed co-ordinate system, so I inverted the result of the cross product (inside the Cross function).

Edit: As accurately stated, I missed off the vertex indices. They are indexed so that each bit indicates the corner on one axis- that is, 0 indicates the right, the top, and the back, in that order.

Also, I apologize for the generally low quality of the question, but I have no idea what else to add. I've got no compiler warnings or errors, and not enough understanding to make sense of anything I might read in the debugger- this is outside my normal field. And the code compiles with a relatively obvious implementation of `Vector` and `AABB`.

Comment: Seriously?  You're writing a "here is my code.  where is the bug?" question?

Comment: It helps if you describe how you have indexed your frustum vertices.

Comment: @Oli: What more do I have to offer? I don't have any compiler warnings or errors, for example, and I sure don't understand this well enough to make any sense of anything I might see in the debugger.

Comment: Can you not construct a test harness that proves it does the "right thing" in isolation?

Comment: @Oli: It almost certainly doesn't do the right thing in any situation. If it did, I wouldn't need the help.

Comment: As an aside, I actually hadn't noticed how poor my question was until you pointed it out. At least the relevant code is very small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this comes down to your labelling of the vertices and the order in which you specify the points. You should be consistent in the direction in which you specify the vertices, clockwise or counter-clockwise depending on your coordinate system. This should be with respect to looking at the outward face (or the internal face depending how you look at it).

To my mind it looks like you have normals pointing in the same direction which is wrong.

[image]

So specifying those surfaces counter-clockwise about the normal gives me

```
   0 1 2
   5 4 7
   1 5 6
   4 0 3
   3 2 6
   1 0 4
```

Your example of 0 1 2 and 4 5 6 yields 2 normals pointing the the same direction, when they should be pointing in opposite directions

Comment: Re-ordering my planes as you specified was a big improvement, but I'm not all the way out of the woods yet. The culling works correctly in some regions, but not in others. Going to modify it slightly as my vertex indices are somewhat different to yours. As an aside- I have an LH co-ordinate system, does that require clockwise or anti-clockwise ordering?

Comment: Guess that it requires clockwise. I re-ordered my vertices to match your indexing, and then I swapped the first and last of each component, and now it's working! you r the winrar